# Where does the Document Viewer (Evince) store history?

Tags: 16.04, evince

I would like to access （to view） the list of "Recently viewed" in *Evince* documents from the terminal, without starting *Evince*. Or maybe can I find a text document where this list is stored? I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Paradisally, I would like to find a complete list of *Evince* documents opened during the previous session or at least a history file, where opened documents are listed together with the dates of opening or at least in the order of opening.

Can you guys help me with this?

**Update:**
Unfortunately, in my system *recently-used.xbel* is a really short file. It is just 218 bytes and contains nothing related to Evince.

Comment: When I open Evince after an unexpected shutdown, the list of "Recently viewed" documents appears. How can I view this list without accessing Evince?

Answer (score 3):

By running `strace -e open evince some.pdf` I was able to find the path used and it is

```
~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel
```

I have verified that this is the case for both 14.04 and 16.04. This file contains recently used items from many applications, so you'd need to filter it by application name. The file is in XML format, so if you want any sort of automated processing it needs to involve an XML parser.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately, in my system _recently-used.xbel_ contains nothing at all related to _Evince_

Comment: @user10805276 Maybe you didn't open anything with evince recently. I suggest you just try the `strace` command yourself to see if it uses a different path on your system (I don't see why it would though).

Comment: Will `strace` change access logs of Evince or access logs to Evince? If no, then I will try it. Yes, there had been about a dozen of pdf files opened with Evince during the previous session. The first of them was opened several months ago and the last one just a day before the shut down. In fact, on another computer `recently-used.xbel` is indeed full of data with many "Recently viewed" files recorded. I do not know why nothing is recorded on the computer I am working with.

Comment: @user10805276, `grep evince ...recently-used.xbel` ? it might be useful to update evince...

Comment: @user10805276 Do you have more than one username on the machine? Maybe you were using a different username. Or maybe evince wasn't given a chance to save its recently viewed list. And running `strace -e open evince some.pdf` will do exactly the same that `evince some.pdf`. Only difference is that you also get some additional output in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

(first Install `xidel` xml/xpath processor if not yet installed)

`~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel` is an XML document with bookmarks of
recently used documents.

In order to extract
the filenames of the `evince` entries, we must provide a XPath expression that:

- looks for bookmarks with attribute `name` = "Document Viewer",
- and print the `href` for levels up

```
xidel -e '//*[@name="Document Viewer"]/../../../../@href' ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately, in my system _recently-used.xbel_ contains nothing at all related to _Evince_

Comment: @user10805276, try to `locate recently-used.xbel`